# PostgreSQL - getting an error when listing databases with message "ERROR: column d.daticu does not exist"

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql, enterprisedb

what could be causing the error below when listing databases in PostgreSQL.

I have 2 clusters running on the same machine under different ports and different data directories. The command works fine when I connect to one of them but fails when I connect to the other.

One cluster is using the PostgreSQL database community version while the other is using the EnterpriseDB Advanced Server 12.1.2 postgres platform but seated on the same machine though different directories.

My psql client version is `psql (EnterpriseDB) 12.1.2` and the database version is `PostgreSQL 12.1, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit`

Error being experienced is:

```
postgres=# \l
ERROR:  column d.daticu does not exist
LINE 6:        d.daticu as "ICU",
               ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "d.datacl".
```

[image]

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?  It seems really clear.

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting a Postgres 12 server? What does `select version();`  give you?

Comment: Challenge is I am just listing databases and not running a select statement. Where is that column "daticu" supposed to be created. It seems to be something within the query the command is running.

Comment: I have added the screenshot with the 2 versions of psql and database version

Comment: If you run `psql -E` you will see the query that `\l` uses. But "vanilla" Postgres does indeed not have a column `pg_database.daticu` - I guess that's some kind of bug in the Enterprise DB version of `psql`. You can either contact them, or use `psql` from a "community" Postgres

Comment: Probably @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks and let me try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server is open source PostgreSQL, while `psql` is EnterpriseDB's fork.

EnterpriseDB must have hacked up their `pg_database` to include an additional column, and the query run for `\l` references that column. Now open source PostgreSQL doesn't have that column, so the query fails.

Use `psql` from the same distribution as the server for best results.

Comment: Exactly. Thanks Laurenz.
I used a psql from the same distribution as the open source postgresql and worked fine.